# Sublime text - Exclude file in root folder (but not anywhere else)

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Given a file `foo.html`

How would I exclude a specific file from the root folder of the project but not anywhere else?

I've tried:

```
"file_exclude_patterns":[
    "foo.html" // ignores everywhere
]

"file_exclude_patterns":[
    "./foo.html" // does nothing
]

"file_exclude_patterns":[
    "/foo.html" // does nothing
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was only able to do it by specifying the name of the root folder:

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["project_folder/foo.html"]
```

Comment: Right, never occurred to me :) I was falsely thinking that sublime knows automatically the root folder, therefor I could not specify it directly.. do you happen to know how to do this only in one project and not others?

Comment: @vsync Could you clarify what you mean by "only in one project"?

Comment: imagine I have lots of similar projects, accessed from the "projects" in the top bar menu. I want to have different exclude patterns, per project, because what I might exclude in one, I will want to be included in another.

Comment: @vsync Do you have a separate `sublime-project` file for each project? If so, put the exclude pattern in each project's `sublime-project` file.